# Non-existent context variable, not allowing input to show in desired location

Tags: c#

I am working on a silly little terminal app that displays the current time as well as the time the user gets out of work. I have a slight issue. Before the "Work exit time" was static I set it to 6:00:00pm I am trying to take that and allow for user input of the subject. Now my code works to get the variable set. However I cant place it [The variable for workOut] where I want it to go.

Here is what I have so far:

```
namespace timerconsole
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public void run ()
        {
            int width = 35;
            int height = 10;

            Console.SetWindowPosition(0, 0); 
            Console.SetWindowSize(width, height); 
            Console.SetBufferSize(width, height); 
            Console.SetWindowSize(width, height);
            Console.WriteLine ("What time do you leave work today: ");

            String workTime = Console.ReadLine ();
            int workOut;
            int.TryParse (workTime, out workOut);

            TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(Tick);

            // create a one second timer tick
            Timer stateTimer = new Timer(callback, null, 0, 1000);

            // loop here forever
            for (; ; ) { }
        }

        static public void Tick(Object stateInfo)
        {
            Console.Clear ();
            Console.WriteLine("The time is: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + "\nWork Target: {0}", workOut); // workOut is my issue. It says "workOut does not exist in current context"
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            MainClass tc = new MainClass ();
            tc.run ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `However I cant place it where I want it to go.` I have NO idea what you're talking about. Please be more specific with what you want your code to do and what the issue is that you're currently running into.

Comment: I mean I cant place the variable workOut where I want it to go to display the user input for the time they leave work.

Comment: Your identation was atrocious. Please don't use tabulation on your markdown.

Comment: Oh. You have the error as a comment way inside your code. Try to put all the relevant context and errors separate from the code itself.

Comment: @Renan Thanks for the advice -- I am using Xamarin studio for the moment. This is not eclipse where I can just ctrl + f and it formats all my code for me in a nice neat orderly set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `workOut` as an integer within the scope of `run()`. It does not exist outside that method, let alone accessible to a static method. Try moving the definition of `workOut` outside of the `run` method and declare it as `static`.

```
namespace timerconsole
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static int workOut; /* Here */

        public void run ()
        {
            int width = 35;
            int height = 10;

            Console.SetWindowPosition(0, 0); 
            Console.SetWindowSize(width, height); 
            Console.SetBufferSize(width, height); 
            Console.SetWindowSize(width, height);


            Console.WriteLine ("What time do you leave work today: ");

            String workTime = Console.ReadLine ();

            int.TryParse (workTime, out workOut);

            TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(Tick);

            // create a one second timer tick
            Timer stateTimer = new Timer(callback, null, 0, 1000);

            // loop here forever
            for (; ; ) { } /* You may want to use Thread.Sleep to not consume *all* of the CPU */
        }

        static public void Tick(Object stateInfo)
        {
            Console.Clear ();
            Console.WriteLine("The time is: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + "\nWork Target: {1}", workOut);
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            MainClass tc = new MainClass ();
            tc.run ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, but its still not showing up where I am trying to place it:  Console.WriteLine("The time is: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + "\nWork Target: {0}", workOut);

Comment: `workOut` will never be written to the console in the `Tick` method. The correct string formatting should be: `Console.WriteLine( "The time is: {0}\nWork Target: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString( "h:mm:ss" ), workOut );`